# python 2, julia and R kernels are dead but python 3 in jupyter (ubuntu). How to get back to a sane environnement?

Tags: r, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

After having upgrade ipython and tried to install R kernel in jupyter, I can't run anymore any notebook with a python 2 kernel (or with a R kernel or a julia kernel) on jupyter (ubuntu 15.04).

Jupyter was installed using `sudo pip install -U jupyter[all]`

I also notice that I can't use the ipython version from the repository after if i remove the version installed with pip.In that case, I have :

```
$ ipython notebook
bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
jeanpat@jeanpat-WA50SHQ:~$ which ipython
/usr/bin/ipython
```

Trying to run ipython as follow do not solve:

```
$ /usr/bin/ipython notebook
2015-08-24 17:50:38.150 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/jeanpat/.ipython/profile_default'
2015-08-24 17:50:38.157 [NotebookApp] Using system MathJax
2015-08-24 17:50:38.170 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jeanpat
2015-08-24 17:50:38.170 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
2015-08-24 17:50:38.170 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2015-08-24 17:50:38.170 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

(process:7153): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
2015-08-24 17:50:43.499 [NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in /
2015-08-24 17:50:44.319 [NotebookApp] Kernel started: d08486bf-5789-457f-93ec-d06a25def67e
2015-08-24 17:51:15.224 [NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: d08486bf-5789-457f-93ec-d06a25def67e
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /api/kernels/0a726dca-894a-4e7d-8b9c-7d62033632f1/channels?session_id=0DB4052BEBDC48048A7EEAE06B445FE0 (127.0.0.1) 20.41ms referer=None
```

So How can get back to a sane ipython 2 notebook environment (even if R, julia, python3 do not work) ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can only make some educated guesses, since we would need to see more of your environment ($PATH, $PYTHONPATH) you are using to start `ipython`, but here is what I would generally recommend:

1) You possibly have some permission problems, since you installed `jupyter` with `sudo`, something I would not generally recommend.

Either try to run `ipython` with `sudo` to see if that already solves anything or uninstall `ipython` with `sudo pip uninstall ipython` and re-install it with `pip install --user ipython[notebook].

It might also be worth resetting your configuration directory `/home/jeanpat/.ipython`.

2) When installing `ipython` it is important to know which `pip` (and therefore which python environment) you are currently using. Are you using virtual environments? It might be that you are simply starting `ipython` in a `python3` environment and therefore can not run `python2` code.

Just run `python` in the same console you want to start `ipython` from and check if that is generally working correctly and also check which version it brings up (2.X or 3.X)?

3) Depending on your intentions of what to do with `ipython`, many people recommend using [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) to manage python installation and packages. It might be worth looking into this. I am not using it personally, but it might reduce some of the python config headaches I am having lately.

Comment: There' something wrong in my home since jupyter notebook run fine from another account. Up to now deletion of several hidden files/dir (.ipython, .jupyter, ...) didn't fix the environnement (installed with sudo pip ..). When a closed virtualenv is used, jupyter is ok. When jupyter is used from a virtualenv using the system packages (sudo pip), jupyter doesn't run. The guilty may be the R Kernel I tried to install. A real mess ... Anaconda run fine, but miss some packages and I don't known if it can use cuda for some packages.

Comment: Sounds like you should uninstall all those kernels and re-install them one by one to check, if you can't locate the issue better.

Comment: Removing ~/.local/share/jupyter fixed the problem.Running with the debug mode (jupyter notebook --debug) showed me where jupyter was looking for its kernels.